# htaccess simple rewrite rule being ignored

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two rewrite rules, this is what I'm trying to achieve

user link -> internal link

site.com/dir1/dir2/**ab**-mypage.php?page=**3** -> site.com/dir1/dir2/script.php?code=**ab**&page=**3**

site.com/dir1/dir2/**cd**-mypage.php -> site.com/dir1/dir2/script.php?code=**cd**

As you can see, the second one is just the same as the first but with pagination support.

Here is the htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule ^dir1/dir2/(.*)-mypage.php?page=(.*)$ dir1/dir2/script.php?code=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^dir1/dir2/(.*)-mypage.php$ dir1/dir2/script.php?code=$1
```

The pagination rule is being ignored completely, no errors. In my script.php when I print out the querystring, the only variable that is present is **code**. I need the page number to be present as well for the second rule.

**Edit:**
Incase anyone else has this problem, this might help: the question mark (?) is the problem, if I use a different character it works and I get both variables. This may be a solution if you don't care about the question mark. To keep the question mark, use the accepted answer to resolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making 2 rules, use [QSA] (which stands for Query String Append) - it will append the original query string to the modified one:

```
RewriteRule ^dir1/dir2/(.*)-mypage.php$ dir1/dir2/script.php?code=$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Query string is being ignored.  You don't need the first rule, just use the QSA flag:

```
RewriteRule ^dir1/dir2/(.*)-mypage.php$ dir1/dir2/script.php?code=$1 [QSA]
```